# Create Web server using Node js model MVC

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to create a web server, and I'm using to MVC model so I tried to use routes inside so I don't know how can I do this. in the console log thats return all data otherwise in postman I test it it doesn't works. here is my code.

**AirModel.js :**

```
AirMonitoring.getAllData = (result) =>{
    db.query('SELECT * FROM AirMonitoring', (err, res)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('Error while fetching airMonitoring', err);
            result(null,err);
        }else{
            console.log('AirMonitoring fetched successfully');
            result(null,res);
        }
    })
}
```

**airController.js :**

```
exports.getAllData = (req, res)=> {
        AirModel.getAllData((err, airMonitoring) =>{
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            console.log('data', airMonitoring);
            res.send(airMonitoring)
        })
    }
```

**index.js :**

```
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
console.log("http was created!");

  if(req.url == '/airMonitoring'){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      // get latest record of airMonitoring 
     router.get('/airMonitoring', airController.getAllData);
    
    res.end();  
}
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused regarding your code... In the actual `db.query`, you're not doing anything with the data other than logging it to the console. Why would you expect anything otherwise?

Comment: Yeah I'm connecting with raspberry db, and with the AirModel there is a query getting the data from db so nothing return from the controller I used in routes, why?!

Comment: I'm assuming the `db.connect` code is in your AirModel?? If so, look at the code, you're not returning any of the data, or even assigning it for that matter. You're just logging it to the console. That's why it's not returning anything... Show a little more of your code the surrounds the `db.connect` bit, so I can be sure this is what's happening, and I can give you a working example.

Comment: I updated my question you can check it now

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Checking it out now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what `router` is but I'm assuming it's an express router, and that's not how routing works. Currently you are (re?)defining the route on each request. [The routing page](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) is a good place to start, but basically you need to define the routes once.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/airMonitoring', airController.getAllData);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

And also in your AirModel.js you have an error as far as I can tell, when handling the database error you should provide it as first argument, not second:

```
result(null,err); /* has to be result(err, null) */
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem. I looked right passed the fact that the route was nested in an `if`...

Comment: Not only is it within the request handler, but also nothing is using the router, so even if it were defined properly it would still not make a difference.

Comment: Unless that code was left out of the OP, like much of the code was to begin with. But yes, you are right.